# What's the translation of "trust fund kid" in French?

Tags: traduction, finance

A trust fund kid [is a](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trust%20fund%20kid):

> a kid [whose] whose parents put money in a trust for their child to use.

The connotation is that the family is rather wealthy.

What's the translation of "trust fund kid" in French?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Trust%20fund%20kid%0A&op=translate) and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=trust+fund+kid) didn't help.

Comment: In France, there are no trust funds as we understand them in NA. This article explains this fact: https://www.lesechos.fr/2001/03/le-trust-existe-presque-en-france-1052758 However, there are workarounds as seen here:https://www.lgdj.fr/la-protection-du-patrimoine-fiduciaire-trust-fund-etude-comparee-droit-francais-droit-anglais-9782275044347.html  Cela dit en trouve au Canada: fonds en fiducie et fond fiduciare en Europe. Mais je laisserais l'anglais entre parenthèse. Kids with trust funds don't have to work and are financially funded by these trusts.

Comment: Un gosse qui vit d'un héritage en fiducie, Lien: https://docplayer.fr/9934985-Bien-conseiller-les-clients-ayant-des-liens-avec-les-etats-unis-me-caroline-rheaume-avocate-m-fisc-tep-adm-a-pl-fin.html Me Caroline Rhéaume, avocate, M.fisc., TEP, Adm.A.,Pl.fin.

Comment: En fait la _fiducie_ existe maintenant aussi bien en [France](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070721/LEGISCTA000006118476/#LEGISCTA000006118476) qu'au [Québec](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/showversion/cs/ccq-1991?code=se:1260&pointInTime=20211102#20211102) à part entière. Ça ne fait pas partie du lexique courant assurément. Une fiducie peut exister du vivant du constituant évidemment. Il s'agit d'un patrimoine d'affectation, c'est ça le _fund_.

Comment: It depends on whether you are  looking for metaphor or legal meaning.

Comment: @Lambie While "trust fund" is a legal term, I don't think "trust fund kid" is. And the latter term might be used figuratively for any person who lives off the largesse of rich parents, it doesn't have to be literally through a trust fund.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, trust fund is a legal term, but if you do away with it, you do away with the **idea**.  The French  lawyer in the link I have explains it better than anyone here. After all, she is a lawyer.

Comment: I think there's a slight difference between living off a trust fund and living off your rich parents, in that a trust fund kid will often have little contact with their parents/family (it may be grandparents' money) and will just receive money every month, while in other circumstances a child of rich parents may be living with parents. There is also a stereotype of the trust fund kid travelling the world and maybe living in Bohemian circles (e.g. John Paul Getty III). It's a case of cultural associations, so it may not translate.

Comment: @StuartF I agree with your analysis but that does not mean that the meaning cannot be translated, because it can, especially in reference to a North American (Canada and US) reality. Especially, in a literary context or one that is dealing with the English meaning.

Comment: Peut-être que _jeune [jet setteur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jet-setteur)/-euse_ ou un mot composé avec _membre de la [jet-set](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/jet-set/551162)_, peut traduire certaines des ces caractéristiques-là au besoin...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A literal translation won't work. A couple of idiomatic expressions with a similar meaning, assuming you mean [that one](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trust%20fund%20kid):

> *un **fils à papa***

> *un **gosse de riche***

Both are derogatory. In France, "trusts funds" are not really known or used, so translating it to *fiducie* would lead to an unintelligible expression. The *fils à papa* and *gosses de riches* get their money from their family regardless of the method used.

Here is another *trust fund kid* definition from [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-trust-fund-baby) that more or less match my suggestions:

> A trust fund kid would be someone who was the beneficiary of such a trust. You usually hear it used in a derogatory way to imply that the trust fund kid has probably never had to worry about money their entire life, because they have sufficient income from their trust to live a very comfortable or even extravagant lifestyle.

Expressio translates *[fils à papa](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/fils-a-papa)* to AmE *[Richie Rich](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Richie%20Rich)* defined by the Urban Dictionary as:

> An adolescent/teen/young adult who grows up in a well-to-do family often perceived as spoiled and often tries to get by on family wealth lacking any discernable talent or skill of his/her own.

Comment: — Un gosse blindé (protégé par l'argent) — Un héritier rentier — « Il a le c*l cousu d'or » (familier) — « Son daron l'a fait baron » (argot plutôt entre-deux guerres) — Ses vieux l'ont bourré de tunes  (familier) — « Il/Elle a de quoi, c'est de famille ».

Comment: daddy's boy and a rich did are simply not the idea.

Comment: @Lambie just like translating the English idiom literally to French does not properly convey its meaning, translating the French idioms literally back to English does not either. I assure you, the translations proposed by jlliagre convey pretty much the same idea.

Comment: @Aetol On a en anglais, daddy's boy et rich kid, qui sont un fils à papa et un gosse de riche. L'idée de trust fund n'est pas donné. Tout dépend de ce que le OP veut dire et le contexte.

Comment: @Lambie je ne pense pas que le but de OP est d'entrer dans les détails des finances de la personne. Comme jlliagre l'a expliqué, "trust fund kid" évoque principalement certaines attitudes et comportements, et "gosse de riche" ou "fils à papa" évoquent essentiellement la même chose. Ce sont des idiomes, le sens littéral est secondaire, voire même sans importance.

Comment: @Aetol As a native English speaker, I disagree. A trust fund is very specific. A rich kid and a daddy's boy also exist in English and do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie "A rich kid and a daddy's boy also exist in English and do not mean the same thing." Yes, they don't mean the same thing as "gosse de riche" or "fils à papa".

Comment: @Aetol I quote myself: "A rich kid and a daddy's boy also exist in English and do not mean the same thing." And I clarify by adding:  "**as a trust fund kid**". Please do not manipulate what I am saying. Thank you.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not "manipulating what you're saying", I'm pointing out they don't mean the same thing as those French idioms either. Since they don't mean the same thing as either of the things being discussed, they're simply irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

The expression *Être né avec une cuillère en argent dans la bouche* would have the same meaning.

As The [Académie Française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/etre-ne-avec-une-cuillere-dargent-ou-avec-une-cuillere-dor-dans-la-bouche) mentions, it comes from the exact [same expression in English](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/born-with-a-silver-spoon-in-your-mouth): *born with a silver spoon in your mouth*.

Comment: This is not the term. Born with a silver spoon in the mouth is not the same as trust fund kid.

Comment: @Lambie I agree that it's not exactly the same but it's closely related, it conveys the meaning of being from a wealthy family as required. The other options "fils à papa" or "gosse de riche" don't have exactly the same meaning either, but this one is more formal.

Comment: One has to decide whether one wants the legal bit to carry over. Unfortunately, the OP has not answered the question. Also, trust funds are often set up well after birth.